# Titlepage with logo centered at the top

Tags: graphics, titles

I'm having a problem creating a titlepage for my thesis. I started with a simple code:

```
documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{braket}

\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo.pdf}
{\huge \bfseries Title of the thesis}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\LARGE Ruhr-Universit\"at Bochum}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\large Department of Atomistic Modelling and Simulation, ICAMS}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large{Project Work}}\\[2.0cm]
Vorname \textsc{Name}\\[0.3cm]
-----------\\[1.5cm]
\emph{Lecturer:} \\
Dr.~Thomas \textsc{Hammerschmidt}\\

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large May 2014}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The thing is, when I try to increase the size of the logo, it would move to the right. Also, there is a large empty space above it. I need it centered at the top of the page. The first image is what I'm getting, the second one is what I need.

[image: This is what I'm getting]

[image: This is what I should be getting]

Comment: What happens if you put `\\` or `\par` after the logo? Right now, the font size at the end of the paragraph is dictating the line spacing for the logo i.e. `\huge` is determining it. Also, if you don't want vertical space before the logo use `{\centering ....}` rather than `\begin{center}... \end{center}` but you will also lose automatically inserted space at the end. Can you edit your code to specify the dimensions of the logo for `\includegraphics`? Then we can use the `demo` option to reproduce your layout.

Comment: To be honest, i am quite confused now -> http://www.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/cd/rub50/geschaeftsausstattung.html

Comment: Is the design of the titlepage global or does every institute has its own version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. About the blank space above the logo, add some negative spacing before `\includegraphics`, e.g.

   ```
   \vspace*{-6\baselineskip}
   ```

   and some positive spacing after it, e.g.

   ```
   \vspace*{4\baselineskip}
   ```
2. About the image looking shifted to the right, add some horizontal negative spacing before `\includegraphics`, e.g.

   ```
   \hspace*{-0.1\textwidth}
   ```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{braket}

\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{-6\baselineskip}
\hspace*{-0.1\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{logo.pdf}
\par\vspace*{4\baselineskip}
{\huge \bfseries Title of the thesis}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\LARGE Ruhr-Universit\"at Bochum}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\large Department of Atomistic Modelling and Simulation, ICAMS}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large{Project Work}}\\[2.0cm]
Vorname \textsc{Name}\\[0.3cm]
108008112625\\[1.5cm]
\emph{Lecturer:} \\
Dr.~Thomas \textsc{Hammerschmidt}\\

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large May 2014}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @abdu You're welcome. I'm glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Here the package `geometry` can help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image.pdf} % height just for the example

\vspace{2cm}

{\huge \bfseries Title of the thesis\par}

\vspace{1cm}

{\LARGE\scshape Ruhr-Universit\"at Bochum\par}

\vspace{1cm}

{\large\scshape Department of Atomistic Modelling and Simulation, ICAMS\par}

\vspace{2cm}

{\Large\scshape Project Work\par}

\vspace{2cm}

Vorname \textsc{Name}\\[0.3cm]
108008112625\\[1.5cm]
\emph{Lecturer:} \\
Dr.~Thomas \textsc{Hammerschmidt}\\

\vfill

% Bottom of the page
{\large May 2014\par}

\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

With the `pass` option we tell `geometry` to do nothing to the standard page geometry; nonetheless, it allows us to use `\newgeometry` for the title page. If you change your mind and decide to use the `twopage` option, the example will still work.

In the example I removed all unnecessary packages, add them back. If you really use `setspace`, it makes sense to disable the interline spacing in the title page.

[image]